# How to get the name of the daylight savings timezone using Java 8

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone

I have a `ZonedDateTime` (Java 8) and I would like to get the applicable time zone abbreviation. In the case of today (April 20, 2020) and for the time zone “Europe/Amsterdam”, that should be “CEST”.

Here's the relevant snippet from my code:

```
final ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam");
final ZonedDateTime timestamp = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, zoneId);

System.out.println(zoneId.toString());
// OK: Prints “Europe/Amsterdam”

System.out.println(timestamp.getOffset().getId());
// OK: Prints “+02:00”

System.out.println(timestamp.getZone().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH));
// NOK: Prints “CET” instead of “CEST”
```

Any hints? How can I get the appropriate time zone abbreviation with daylight savings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you have already got a date and time in summer

What works for me is formatting a `ZonedDateTime` in the summer time part of the year using a formatter with format pattern `zzz` for the short summer time aware (DST aware) name of the time zone.

In the first part of my answer I am assuming that either you already know that the Netherlands are on summer time on April 20, or you just want the correct abbreviation for that date no matter if it’s standard time (CET) or summer time (CEST).

```
    DateTimeFormatter zoneFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("zzz", Locale.forLanguageTag("nl"));
    final ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam");
    final ZonedDateTime timestamp = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, zoneId);
    String output = timestamp.format(zoneFormatter);
    System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

> CEST

### If you don’t know when summer time (DST) is

If you want the *summer time* (DST) abbreviation independently of any particular date and time, either it’s a bit more complicated than one might have imagined, or I am missing something. I am first findind a `ZonedDateTime` in the summer time part of the year, then formatting it as before.

You might have expected that taking July 1 in any year would work. Not so. Many time zones have used summer time in some years and not in others. And time zones on the southern hemisphere have their winter in July and their summer time part of the year in the opposite part. So for a solution that works across time zones we need to find a summer time programmatically. I am using the zone rules of the time zone for that.

```
    DateTimeFormatter zoneFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("zzz", Locale.forLanguageTag("nl"));
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam");

    // Find a time where summer time (DST) is in effect (if there is one)
    ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();
    Optional<Instant> exampleTime = rules.getTransitions()
            .stream()
            .map(ZoneOffsetTransition::getInstant)
            .filter(i -> ! rules.getDaylightSavings(i).equals(Duration.ZERO))
            .findAny();

    // Format the time found into a zone abbreviation
    String output = exampleTime.map(t -> t.atZone(zone))
            .map(zoneFormatter::format)
            .orElse("No summer time found");

    System.out.println(output);
```

Output is the same as before.

Comment: @ole-v-v Of course; using a `DateTimeFormatter` will work – brilliant. Thanks a heap! I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can use TimeZone Class instead of ZonedDateTime as follow:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam");
System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName(true, 0));
```

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for, because (1) the date/timestamp I have is dynamic, it's not always the same, and (2) `TimeZone` is part of the old pre-Java 8 API.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. No, please not this answer. The `TimeZone` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Presumably this is exactly why the OP is using its modern replacement, `ZoneId` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). So don’t suggest this big step backward.